# pandas: how to see if an (argument) string is in a list of strings that is in a pandas element (sort of a reverse isin)

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "tags": pd.Series([["a", "b"], ["a"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "c"], []]),
    "value": pd.Series([0, 2, 1, 4, 3]),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to select all rows that have a "c" as one of the elements in the "tag" column (as in `df.loc[INSERT_FUNCTION_HERE]`). This is like the pandas call `isin` but backwards; `isin` checks if each element in the column is in the argument list, whereas I want the opposite: for each element in the column, is the argument in that (list) element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode`,

```
idx = df['tags'].explode().eq('c').loc[lambda x: x].index
df.loc[idx, :]
# or use df.reindex(idx)
```

Output:

```
     tags  value
2  [b, c]      1
3  [a, c]      4
```

Explanation:

Use `pd.Series.explode` to breakout elements in the list to lines in a new pd.Series, then check to see if that element equals to 'c' and lastly filter the rows in the new pd.Series using a `lambda x: x` creating a boolean series in `loc` boolean indexing the new series to return only rows with 'c', then use the index from these rows to filter the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df = df[pd.DataFrame(df.tags.tolist()).isin(['c']).any(1).values]
Out[44]: 
     tags  value
2  [b, c]      1
3  [a, c]      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter with a boolean list generated from a list comprehension :

```
df.loc[["c" in entry for entry in df.tags]]

    tags    value
2   [b, c]  1
3   [a, c]  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
df[df['tags'].apply(lambda x: 'c' in x)]
```

It will give output like this.

```
     tags  value
2  [b, c]      1
3  [a, c]      4
```